# Translating a fancy box in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, module, fancybox, translate

How can I translate a fancy box in wordpress? I downloaded the WPML, and loco translate plugins to do this but when I duplicate the module, change its contents and place the duplicate id in my page; the translations aren't showing. Do I need to use another plugin, edit it manually in a php file or something?

Comment: Please see: [Would it be ok to change a downvoted question into a completely different question so you can ask it when post-banned?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265301/would-it-be-ok-to-change-a-downvoted-question-into-a-completely-different-questi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to add custom translation for fancybox, then you can do that by adding new entry to `$.fancybox.defaults.i18n` object, you can use `en` as the base. Then use `lang` option to change language.